# Orderby title and order asc not working true with special char

Tags: php, wordpress

My query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
'orderby'   => 'title',
'order'     => 'ASC',
'showposts' => -1
));
```

But it display not true (please visit http://animevd.com/anime-list). '.' before 'b' and 'b' before '.'

Comment: I can't see the page - "This web page has a redirect loop"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'orderby'   => 'title',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'ASC' ),
    'showposts' => -1
));
```

You can also order by multiple parameters, like:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'orderby' => array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC', 'post_date' => 'DESC' ),
    'showposts' => -1
));
```